# StackingClassifier: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, machine-learning

With the help of GridSearchCV, I selected the optimal parameters for several models. In the end I decided to skip all the models through the StackingClassifier:

```
estimators = [
    ('GaussianNB', GaussianNB(var_smoothing = 0.533669923120631),
     'LogisticRegression', LogisticRegression(C=0.001, 
                                              max_iter=1500, 
                                              penalty='none', 
                                              random_state=42,
                                              solver='newton-cg'),
     'DecisionTreeClassifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.001, 
                                                      criterion='entropy', 
                                                      max_depth=14,
                                                      max_features='auto', 
                                                      random_state=42),
     'RandomForestClassifier', RandomForestClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.001, 
                                                       criterion='entropy', 
                                                       max_depth=14,
                                                       random_state=42),
     'SVC', SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state=42),
     'KNeighborsClassifier', KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='ball_tree', 
                                                 n_neighbors=3),
     'GradientBoostingClassifier', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.2, 
                                                               max_depth=10, 
                                                               max_features='sqrt',
                                                               n_estimators=10, 
                                                               subsample=0.8))]

meta_model = LogisticRegressionCV()

stacking_model = StackingClassifier(estimators = estimators, 
                                    final_estimator = meta_model, 
                                    passthrough = True, 
                                    cv = 5,
                                    verbose = 2).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

As a result, I got this error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3464\4193990893.py in 
> 1 stacking_model = StackingClassifier(estimators = estimators,
> 2                                     final_estimator = meta_model,
> 3                                     passthrough = True,
> 4                                     cv = 5,
> 5                                     verbose = 2).fit(X_train, y_train)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble_stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
> 486         self.*le = LabelEncoder().fit(y)
> 487         self.classes* = self.*le.classes*
> 488         return super().fit(X, self.*le.transform(y), sample_weight)
> 489
> 490     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate="final_estimator*")
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble_stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
> 148         # all_estimators contains all estimators, the one to be fitted and the
> 149         # 'drop' string.
> 150         names, all_estimators = self._validate_estimators()
> 151         self._validate_final_estimator()
> 152
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
> 245                 " of (string, estimator) tuples."
> 246             )
> 247         names, estimators = zip(*self.estimators)
> 248         # defined by MetaEstimatorMixin
> 249         self._validate_names(names)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @molbdnilo please prefer to add such comments when editing the question instead of here

Answer (score 0):

The format of `estimators` is incorrect: it should be a list of 2-tuples:

```py
estimators = [
    ('GaussianNB', GaussianNB(var_smoothing = 0.533669923120631)),
    ('LogisticRegression', LogisticRegression(C=0.001, 
                                              max_iter=1500, 
                                              penalty='none', 
                                              random_state=42,
                                              solver='newton-cg')),
    ...
]
```